# mount command taking 13 minutes to execute

Tags: debian, mount

Aspire One Cloudbook 14 (A01-431-C8G8)
Linux kernel 4.19 
Debian 10

I have a USB 3.0 stick plugged into a USB 3.0 slot in the machine. I have just issued the `cp` command to copy all files in one of the partitions in the machine (7GB according to `du -hs`) to one of the partitions in the stick. I estimated the transfer will end in about 70m.

Immediately after `cp` I did `mount -tauto  /dev/sda1 /cine`, where `/dev/sda1` is another partition in the stick. The command took 13m to complete. How can this be?

Answer (score 2):

After you invoked unmount the kernel started flushing the dirty buffers and since your flash drive random IO access speed is terribly low, your mount command (which was reading data from the drive) started to compete with the writing performed by the kernel in order to flush the dirty buffers.

Here's how I solved this for myself:

```
/etc/sysctl.d/dirty.conf

vm.dirty_background_bytes = 33554432
vm.dirty_bytes = 134217728
```

LWN has more info on the issue (which is unfortunately still not addressed):

https://lwn.net/Articles/572911/

Comment: Well, Linux isn't so good after all. Thanks. I think the OS should be smart enough to figure out how not to make me wait 11m to do a mount.